# Can't remove 2 entries in the download window

Tags: firefox, downloads

1. I started downloads of several files in Firefox.
2. While downloading, there was no free space left on my hard disk.
3. I got some error messages (with wording like "not enough free space" and "cancelled download").
4. I deleted all newly downloaded files (the completed and the cancelled ones) manually.

**Problem**: In the download window two of these downloads are still listed and can't be removed.

[image: Screenshot of Firefox download window]

As you can see on the screenshot, I can't clear the list by clicking the button in the bottom left corner (it's inactive).

Selecting "Pause" or "Cancel" in the context menu doesn't do anything.

Comment: did you try shutting down firefox and rebooting it? also, can you explain why you think this is ubuntu related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restarted Ubuntu and the problem is "fixed": the two entries were still listed in the Downloads window but marked as "completed". I wondered how this could happen and opened the download folder. And to my surprise these two files were there, fully downloaded. The timestamp of last change corresponds to the time where I restarted Ubuntu/Firefox.

So Firefox seems to have started the download again after restarting.